# Extracting digits on a line below a specific line with a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If I have the following lines within a text file:

```
5 HIV serotype 2
    3838 28282 4949
        383 292 1012

10 SIV unknown serotype
    3939 433 332 3222 122
       3221 222 345 433 393 303
```

...and I wanted to extract the digits from below the 5 HIV serotype line AND above the 10 SIV unknown serotype line, I assumed the following would work:

```
import re
with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
        line = line.strip()
        if re.match('\d\s+HIV.*?(\d+)', line, re.MULTILINE):
            print(re.match())
```

However, nothing is returned.

Thank you.

Comment: I am expecting the following  string of digits: 2 3838 28282 4949 383 292 1012

Comment: Are there multiple such blocks in the file or only one as in your question?

Comment: There are multiple blocks within the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` and `re.search` . `re.search` does the job of matching the `HIV` section where `re.findall` pick the numbers from matched section.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''5 HIV serotype 2
    3838 28282 4949
        383 292 1012

10 SIV unknown serotype
    3939 433 332 3222 122
       3221 222 345 433 393 303'''
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', re.search(r'(?s)\d+\s+HIV\s+(.*?)(?:\n\n|$)', s).group(1))
['2', '3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty sure that those lines exist in your file with that format, you don't need regex then. You an just use `takewhile` and `dropwhile` functions from `itertools` module:

```
In [131]: with open('test.txt') as f:
              dropwhile(lambda x: x.startswith('5 HIV serotype'), f); next(f)
              lines = takewhile(lambda x: not x.startswith('10 SIV unknown'), f)
              print([j for l in lines for j in l.strip().split() if j])
   .....:     
['3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012']
```

Note that his is a very much optimize approach in terms of both memory and run time when you're dealing with large data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code (explanations as comments):

```
with open("serotypes.txt", "r") as ff:
    lines = ff.read().split("\n")                   # read file and split lines;
lines = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), lines))       # trim each line;
lines.reverse()                                     # reverse the list for pop to work below;
outlist = []        # empty output list;
try:                                    
    while True:     # keep reading till exception occurs due to empty lines list
        while True:
            i = lines.pop()                         # ignore all till HIV Line;
            if i.startswith("5 HIV serotype"):              
                outlist.append(i.split("5 HIV serotype")[1].strip())    # append last number of HIV Line;
                break
        while True:
            i = lines.pop()
            if i.startswith("10 SIV unknown serotype"):     # if SIV line found, break out;
                break
            else:
                outlist.extend(i.split())                   # extend (not append) all lines till then to output list;
except:
    pass
print(outlist)
```

Output for file 'serotypes.txt' which contains many text blocks:

```
['2', '3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012', '2', '3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012', '2', '3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012', '2', '3838', '28282', '4949', '383', '292', '1012']
```